# lamps and statistic

Tags: probability, statistics

I tried so hard this question, but I was not be able to answer it.... Could you help me to understand it?

In a supermarket 2,000 lamps from three different factories A, B and C. The A produced 500 lamps 400 of which are perfect. B produced 700 lamps, of which 600 are good and the remaining C, of which 500 good. If randomly placed randomly one of the lamps in the supermarket which the probability that:
a) is perfect?
b) being defective, has been manufactured by A?

Comment: Look for something called the law of total probability and then at Bayes' theorem in your probability/statistics textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a supermarket 2,000 lamps from three different factories A, B and C.

Let $A, B, C$ be the event that a sampled lamp comes from the respective factory.  Let $G$ be the event that the sampled lamp is 'good' (a.k.a. 'perfect'), and $G^\complement$ the event that it is not 'good'.

> The A produced 500 lamps 400 of which are perfect.

$$\mathsf P(A) = 5/20 \\ \mathsf P(G\mid A) = 4/5$$

> B produced 700 lamps, of which 600 are good

$$\mathsf P(B) = 7/20 \\ \mathsf P(G\mid B) = 6/7$$

> and the remaining (2000-500-700) C, of which 500 good.

$$\mathsf P(C) = 8/20 \\ \mathsf P(G\mid C) = 5/8$$

> If randomly placed randomly one of the lamps in the supermarket which the probability that: a) is perfect?

Use the Law of Total Probability to find $\mathsf P(G)$ from the above.

> b) being defective, has been manufactured by A?

Use Bayes' Rule to find $\mathsf P(A\mid G^\complement)$

Answer (score 0):

The number of good lamps = 400+600+500=1500

Total number of lamps=2000

a) probability of randomly choosing perfect lamps = P(A) = 1500/2000=0.75

b) Using Bayes' theorem, P(A|B) = P(B|A)*P(A)/P(B)

A = event of bulbs being manufactured by A

B= event of bulbs being defective

P(A|B) = probability of occurrence of event A given that B has already occurred.

P(B|A) = 1/5=0.2

P(B) = 0.25

P(A) = 500/2000 = 0.25

hence, P(A|B) = 0.2